# xfce: How do I get standard Norwegian keyboard layout with dead keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xfce

In Xubuntu's keyboard layout settings, if I choose "Bruk systemstandardene" (Use system standard) for my keyboard layout, I get the Norwegian "no" layout with deadkeys (same as `setxkbmap no` it seems). The key to the left of backspace gives me \, but with shift it gives a dead "`".

But if I want several keyboard layouts, there's only Norwegian *without* dead keys in the list (while e.g. Mac and Northern Saami variants both have with and without-versions):
[image: why no standard Norwegian with dead keys]

Is this a bug? Where's Norwegian "no" with dead keys? It's obviously on my system since it's the system standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out as I was asking.

It's possible to click the category itself, ie. the line above "Northern Saami (Norway)" in the screenshot.

(Not quite obvious, since it's quite a stretch to call e.g. Northern Saami a variant of Norwegian …)

Comment: Your ask and answer time is same. I think you wanted to share a finding. Accept the answer to help the site